# Azure Virtual Machine Capture

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have a Windows Server running as a Virtual Machine on Azure that I have installed SQL Enterprise on.  I installed SQL Server onto a new drive (E:) so that the C: drive would remain for the OS.

I followed the instructions on how to use sysprep and basically capture the image to use going forward for new instances.  After following these steps and deploying a new vm with this image, nothing worked.  It thought SQL was installed (it wasn't).  It also didn't know anything about the additional drives or VHDs.

I came across this Blog post from the Azure team and it references a powershell command `Save-AzureVMImage` that may be what I'm looking for with the new "Virtual Machine Image".

Ultimately what I want is to have an image that I can use to deploy a new fully functional Windows Server instance with SQL Enterprise installed and the additional VHDs being used...  Can someone point me in the right hemisphere on this please...

Answer (score 1):

Save-AzureVMImage until the build 2014 only captures OS disk and not the data disk, since your SQL is installed on a separate mapped drive a data disk. That will not be part of the snapshot\sysprep process.

There is something called VMImages recently launched which captures data disks along side OS disks.You will have to update Azure Commandlets to find more options while capturing Image of a running VM, Refer to the blogs below for more detailed solution

http://vishwanathsrikanth.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/windows-azure-vmimages-updates-to-clonevm-powershell-script/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/14/vm-image-blog-post.aspx

Happy Coding !!